# How can I get a key from the value in Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

My Firebase structure is as below.
I'm using python to use firebase,
and also I use Pyrebase.

I want to get a key, which looks like '288xxxxxx'
from the value(busStopName).
Can I get the answer in Pyrebase?

Thank you in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, based on the [documentation](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#database)

```
searched_bus = db.child("asanbus").order_by_child("busStopName").equal_to("XYZ").get()
for bus in searched_bus.each():
    print(bus.key())
```

**Assumption**: there is only one record corresponding to `busStopname = "XYZ"`. If not the case, you may do:

```
searched_bus = db.child("asanbus").order_by_child("busStopName").equal_to("XYZ").limit_to_first(1).get()
```